# Android Highlight in WebView not going away

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

In my web app, running in an android WebView, whenever I click on something, or navigate somewhere, that container div is highlighted blue. Sometimes only for a moment, but sometimes until you click somewhere else.

I'm not sure if it's a focus issue, a tab-order issue, a webview issue, or something else entirely.

I tried adding this to my CSS:

```
    * {
          -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
          -webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
       }
```

I also tried adding this to the webView Settings:

```
   webSettings.setLightTouchEnabled(false);
```

but no dice.

How can I either make it so that webview doesn't focus on these divs, or the highlight color is invisible/opaque/transparent?

Answer (score 1):

I made this work for a WebView in Android app with the following:

```
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
```

in your css file?

Here is a link: [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

It is in regards to text, but might be helpful in your situation.